# Here is my description. Now, tell me, what am I?

Tags: riddle, wordplay

This is not a location, but if you specifically spelt me with an 's' you would spot me in several bedrooms.

I could go on, but I feel that's enough of me for now.

What am I?

**HINT 1: 29/06/19**

> word sword spelt pelt

**HINT 2: 30/06/19**

> no longer a location

**HINT 3: 01/07/19 (1)**

> synonyms of location

**HINT 4: 01/07/19 (2)**

> an act commonly performed in the bedroom

**HINT 5: 02/07/19 (1)**

> I could go on, but I feel that's enough *(insert here)* for now.

**HINT 6: 02/07/19 (2)**

> With this meta-hint, I have made a comprehensive description of the word at hand.

**HINT 7: 03/07/19**

> Synonym of location beginning with p

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Edit: New answer after a lot more hints...

> Exposition

Here is why:

> *"This is not a location"*  -> it sounds like a location, but is something different
>  *"but if you specifically spelt me with an 's' you would spot me in several bedrooms"*  -> **s**exposition, well, google it yourself
>  *"I could go on, but I feel that's enough of me for now."* -> exposition means explanation, so enough hints for now
>  HINT 1: Add an s
>  HINT 2: no longer a location = *ex* position
>  HINT 3: *position* is synonym of location, see HINT 7, starts with *p*
>  HINT 4: reference to sex
>  HINT 5: enough exposition means enough explanations/hints given
>  HINT 6: a hint saying enough hints given is indeed a hint for our problem
>  HINT 7: see HINT 3

Old answer:

My first though after reading the question was

> we need to find a word starting with an $s$ which can be found in a bedroom but without the $s$ it means "location" or is a "location"

But Hint 1 tells me

> word -> sword
>  spelt -> pelt
>  so i can add $s$ or remove it

Hint 2 tells me

> after removing or adding the $s$ it is no longer a location

Hint 3 tells me

> it is not an exlicit location but a synonym

So after rereading Hint 1

> I noticed, that "spelt" is a word from the question, so I searched again and found
>  $$spot$$
>  which is an synonym of location and after removing the $s$ we have $$pot$$ which of course in modern times is rarely found in bedrooms but it fits all the hints.

Answer (score 7):

Grasping at straws here, you are

> The letter **X**.

This is not a location,

> ...but **X** *marks* the spot

but if you specifically spelt me with an 's' you would spot me in several bedrooms.

> *X* is spelled **E X**.  Prepend an **S** as shown in Hint 1 and you have something that you might see in bedrooms, if you're the sort to go looking.

HINT 1: 29/06/19

> `word sword spelt pelt` ... tells us to put the 's' in front of you

HINT 2: 30/06/19

> `no longer a location` ... "no longer" = **ex**

HINT 3: 01/07/19 (1)

> `synonyms of location` ... spots, which Xs mark

HINT 4: 01/07/19 (2)

> `an act commonly performed in the bedroom` ... well, yes.

... You cad. :)

Comment: You're the closest one yet! You've almost nailed all of the hints. rot13(fcbg vfa'g gur evtug flabalz.)

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a whole lot of details here to go on, but some things that several bedrooms would all have in common, all together and guaranteed, would be:

> Wall**s**, ceiling**s**, floor**s**, and doorway**s**.

Comment: Well, you could say that for pretty much anything, just make it plural.

Answer (score 1):

my best guess is

> alarm clocks. They are in several bedrooms - "I could go on" may refer to the running time

Answer (score 1):

I guess:

> "eats"

Because:

> Here is my description = **deets** (details)
>  A location = **street**, maybe "suite"
>  Spelt = **wheat**
>  Spelled with 's', spot = **seat**
>  In bedrooms = **sheet**
>  Could go on = **beat** (as in: the beat goes on)
>  Enough of me = **replete**, or maybe "complete"